# Merge multiple files by common field - Unix

Tags: file, merge

I have hundreds of files, each with two columns :

For example :

file1.txt

```
ID Value1
1   40
2   30
3   70
```

file2.txt

```
ID Value2
1   50
2   70 
3   20
```

And so on, till

file150.txt

```
ID Value150
1   98
2   52
3   71
```

How do I merge these files based on the first column (which is common). My output should be

```
ID Value1 Value2...........Value150
1   40     50                98
2   30     70                52
3   70     20                71
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. using **cut and paste combination** to solve the file merging problem on three files or more. cd to the folder only contains file1, file2, file3, ... file150:

   ```
   i=0
   cut -f 1 file1 > delim   ## use first column as delimiter
   for file in file*
   do
           i=$(($i+1))  ## for adding count to distinguish files from original ones
           cut -f 2 $file > ${file}__${i}.temp
   done
   paste -d\\t delim file*__*.temp > output
   ```
2. Another solution is using **join** to merge two files once by steps.

   ```
   join -j 1 test1 test2  | join -j 1 test3 - | join -j 1 test4 -
   ```